# H800 Logitech headphones not working properly

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth, skype, headphones

So, I bought these headphones, and I'm trying to use it with Ubuntu.

Using it to listen to music (A2DP profile) works perfectly. However, when I try to use them with Skype, Google Hangouts, or anything else where I need full duplex (HSP/HFP), that's when problems arise.

This is the output from syslog when I pair them:

```
Oct  3 13:43:35 padme kernel: [ 5864.309541] input: 00:0D:44:FA:9B:B6 as /devices/virtual/input/input12
Oct  3 13:43:35 padme pulseaudio[3200]: [pulseaudio] module-bluetooth-device.c: Failed to acquire transport /org/bluez/714/hci0/dev_00_0D_44_FA_9B_B6/fd0
Oct  3 13:43:35 padme bluetoothd[714]: /org/bluez/714/hci0/dev_00_0D_44_FA_9B_B6/fd1: fd(30) ready
Oct  3 13:43:35 padme rtkit-daemon[3202]: Successfully made thread 7321 of process 3200 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Oct  3 13:43:35 padme rtkit-daemon[3202]: Supervising 7 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Oct  3 13:43:40 padme bluetoothd[714]: Audio connection got disconnected
```

From "Audio Setup" choose "HSP/HFP"

```
Oct  3 13:44:05 padme bluetoothd[714]: /org/bluez/714/hci0/dev_00_0D_44_FA_9B_B6/fd0: fd(24) ready
Oct  3 13:44:05 padme rtkit-daemon[3202]: Successfully made thread 7335 of process 3200 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Oct  3 13:44:05 padme rtkit-daemon[3202]: Supervising 8 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Oct  3 13:44:10 padme bluetoothd[714]: Audio connection got disconnected
```

When I click the "Mono" button under the "Speaker placement and testing", nothing happens and the button stay pressed. When I try to play music from Amarok, Youtube video or anything, there's no sound at all and applications just hold, as if they are waiting for the hardware... Like, you hit play on Amarok, and you can see that time is sitting still at 0:00. Testing MIC also doesn't work, neither from the Audio Setup, nor any application such as Skype.

When switching to A2DP, I see this in the logs:

```
Oct  3 13:47:19 padme bluetoothd[714]: Audio connection got disconnected
Oct  3 13:47:19 padme bluetoothd[714]: /org/bluez/714/hci0/dev_00_0D_44_FA_9B_B6/fd2: fd(29) ready                                                                      
Oct  3 13:47:19 padme rtkit-daemon[3202]: Successfully made thread 7359 of process 3200 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.                                         
Oct  3 13:47:19 padme rtkit-daemon[3202]: Supervising 8 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
```

process 3200 is this:

```
/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

Under A2DP, everything works fine and as expected... music plays, youtube videos work, etc...

It is worth noting that the headphones work fine when paired to a phone. When listening to music, A2DP profile is used, and when a call is in place, it switches fine to HFP and mic and speakers work fine.

Software and versions:

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bits
- KDE 4.14.0
- bluez 4.101-0ubuntu13
- bluetooth 4.101-0ubuntu13
- pulseaudio 4.0-0ubuntu11

Also, when using the headphones with the provided USB dongle, they work fine, the only issue is related to bluetooth connection on Ubuntu.

Let me know if you need any additional log, or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to report that after upgrading to Kubuntu 15.04, and KDE 5, switching between bluetooth profiles works fine.

Comment: You are lucky. I'm stuck with Linux Mint 19.3 and can't seem to find a way to fix this incredibly annoying bug.